# Can we add extra container to page header in Magento 2?

Tags: custom, header, magento2.4.5, custom-theme, containers

I need to add a extra container to page header.

https://prnt.sc/dq9LDPcioxvJ

please check attached screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="extra.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="free-shipping-container-class" after="header.panel.wrapper">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="free-shipping" template="Vendor_Module::freeshipping.phtml" />
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/freeshipping.phtml**

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Free Shipping</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using Module (app/code)

1.you can create
**`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <referenceContainer name="header.container">
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mini.container"
           template="Vendor_Module::freeshipping.phtml" before="header.panel.wrapper" />
     </referenceContainer>
  </page>
```

2.**`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/freeshipping.phtml`**

```
<div class="custom-container">
    <div style="border:1px solid red; text-align: center" id="test123"><p>Free Shipping</p></div>
</div>
```

[image: image here]

- Without module if you need to add in your theme do like this.

  Create following file under your theme

1. create defualt.xml file:

> **`app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` And add above code of defualt.xml file (app/code) in your xml**

2. create freshipping.phtml file:

> **`app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/freshipping.phtml`
> And add above code of freshipping.phtml file (app/code) in your
> phtml**

**please let me know it's working or not**

Comment: Custom module or we can add above files in custom theme

Comment: above example for custom module(app/code/vender/module) you can also add in custom theme if you need add in custom theme then please let me know

Comment: I tried above example but container not showing.

Comment: flush the cache and check it's working on my side you can see the attached screenshot

Comment: I am using Rubix theme. Can I add code in custom theme instead of module.

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: I tried but not showing!

Comment: once you need to check your customization